# How many CPUs does the CloudSQL instance have?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

How many CPUs does the `CloudSQL` instance have?

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing) says it is `an appropriate amount of CPU` and it is not clear.

Comment: I guess tier code means the number of CPUs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does not provide this information. The only documentation shared in the ['Pricing'](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing) Cloud SQL page states:

> "Each instance tier comes with the RAM shown above, along with an appropriate amount of CPU."

The Google Cloud SQL public issue tracker reveals [one request](https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/detail?id=66&can=1&q=cpu&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20log#makechanges) for CPU information to which the response was:

> Regarding the CPU for each instance type, Cloud SQL provides a sufficient amount of CPU for the ram.  We do not expose the exact CPU allocated.

The status flagged as a `Note` indicates this request will not be fulfilled.

I suspect with scalability in mind, that Google's strategy scaling through instance replication and distribution rather than augmenting CPU on individual instances though I don't know this for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Not just the number of CPUs, but also the frequency of the CPUs.

From the word "Tier", we know the CPU speed/performance of that tier is proportional to the Tier number. For example, D32 is twice faster than D16. I think D0 should really be called D0.5.